# Strange brush behaviour on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When using the brush or eraser tool a strange thing happens that I can only describe as lag or jitter.

[image]

As you can see from the image the ridges in the mask it should be smooth. To the point when I use the shift key to create a straight line it still jitters.

All this happens with the stock/default brushes.

What is that and how can I stop it from happening?

My PC is a pretty hefty system 3.7 i7 quad core 8gb ram dedicated GPU etc.

Comment: Fix the spacing----Brush Settings -> Brush Tip Shape -> Spacing.

Comment: That fixed it, strange that it would be on 25% as default.

Comment: 25% is pretty good fir small brushes. Large brushes dont go for precision anyway so t is a good tradeoff between speed and accuracy

Comment: Ryan, you should put that as the answer instead of a comment.